# WiFi not starting : accidentally deleted wpa_supplicant file

Tags: wi-fi, 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g, wpa-supplicant

My device is **moto g xt1033 android 5.0.2** (rooted). During my experiments for enabling reverse tethering over USB, I accidentally replaced the original WPA_supplicant file from system/bin folder with the one downloaded from internet.

Now my WiFi , Wi-Fi hotspot won't start.

Comment: Options: 1) use the one from your backup (oh... yeah, I guess it already, so) 2) find someone with the very same device & ROM to get a copy (wrong place here for that), 3) flash your ROM again. And no, a factory-reset won't bring it back.

Comment: Arun, have you noticed what point 2) in my previous comment says? This is the wrong place to ask for sharing files, sorry. You might also wish to consult [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) for a fitting place to your question.

Comment: @Izzy sorry, I'm new here. :)

Comment: finally flashed stock from [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2700502)

Comment: For the "being new": We have a nice [Tour](http://android.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how this site works, and a good [help] (<- recommended reading :) // If your issue is solved: You might consider to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) and accept that answer then, so that becomes clear to possible others in a similar situation. Thanks a lot!